# Text annotations displayed outside map and page boundary on QGIS layout

Tags: qgis

My workspace includes many text annotations. These are not linked to any GIS layer, and they are set as fixed map position. When I open the layout for the project, (to print maps on to PDF) the text annotations are displayed outside the boundary of the map AND outside the boundary of the page. When printing to PDF, the labels overlay the title block at the bottom of the page.

Note: We are using the atlas feature in the project layout.

See the attached screenshot for context. [image]

This was an issue on QGIS 3.12.0, I tried updating to QGIS 3.20.1 and it is still occuring.

The only workaround I can think of is using the plugin 'AnnotationManager' to temporarily turn the annotations which overlap the title block, however this is very inefficient.

Comment: Could you un-blur your image? I cannot see what is going on.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't unblur because of confidentiality

Comment: Perhaps you have 2 map windows. That s the best I can comment for now.

Comment: Thanks @MyGIS
Yes there are two map windows. There is the map window 'map window is here', and the other is a small overview map in the bottom right of the screen. We aren't sure why the text annotations are being drawn outside of the map window !

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Just to be clear, are you trying to turn off the annotations altogether or do you only want to show annotations within the map window?

Comment: Hi @she_weeds. I only want to show annotations in the map window

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Dominic. Unfortunately I don't think there is a fix here. Annotations seem to be a poorly supported feature in QGIS. You may have better luck using an actual data file with the latest in labeling and symbology to annotate your data.